# Angular js router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Добрый день, день хочу сделать следующее: что бы роутинг на сервер отвечал за "глобальные переходы по сайту", а Angular js отвечал за роутинг на местах (например узнать подробней). Стоит ли это делать? И как это организовать?

Answer (score 1):

> Стоит ли это делать?

Насчёт стоит ли это делать решать наверно вам. Я пару раз так делал когда надо было на страничках организовывать сложные формы и таблички. Для меня поддерживать небольшое ангуляр приложение проще чем большую кучу лапши на jQuery.

> И как это организовать?

Просто для каждой страницы пишете своё отдельное ангулровское приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки типа hostname/page1/subpage
Пусть перехватывает backend.
Но в этом случае Вы каждый раз получаете перезагрузку страницы.

Ссылки типа hostname/#/state1/substate1
оставляете на angular. ui-route Вам в помощь.

Но лучше возложить на backend только загрузку первоначальной страницы и
запросы через $http.
В этом случае по ссылкам типа GET (POST, PUT, DELETE) hostname/page1/subpage
должен приходить JSON ответ.

Comment: если использовать `html5mode` все ссылки будут вида _hostname/page1/subpage_

Comment: Тогда backend начнет их перехватывать

Comment: Зависит от настроек сервера